# Can I install the Enlightenment Shell alongside Unity and Gnome3 and choose upon login?

Tags: login-screen, session, lightdm

does anybody know if it is possible to install Enlightenment in Ubuntu (11.10) and be able to choose Unity Gnome or Enlightenment from the login screen? is this at all possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I just did this myself. Just install the E17 package, and you should be up and running.